# What html lang value to use for the Gun language?

Tags: html, lang

What `<html lang=" ">` value should I use for content that is in the **Gun** language? I can't see it listed in any official documents.

Comment: Have you looked for the alternatives? Alada, Alada-Gbe, Egun, Goun, Gu, Gugbe, Gun, Gun-Alada, Gun-Gbe, Gungbe, Seto-Gbe, Toli-Gbe

Comment: @belwood Gungbe. That is what it is also known as. Is there a code for that then?

Comment: Unfortunately, don't know.  I just happened to have that list of names handy.

Comment: @belwood I can't see it here: http://www.w3schools.com/TagS/ref_language_codes.asp

Comment: Have you considered writing one? https://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp47 :-)

Comment: @belwood No. I don't know the language. Someone is translating a webpage into this language that I want to support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Language Subtag Lookup App](http://r12a.github.io/apps/subtags/) suggests that the tag for the Gun language is `lang="guw"`. Ethnologue [agrees](http://www.ethnologue.com/18/language/guw/). Wikipedia makes Gun a member of the [Fon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fon_language) dialect cluster.

Comment: Thanks. Why can't I see `guw` listed on other web pages that show language codes?

Comment: No idea. It is listed in the official [IANA Language Subtag Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry/language-subtag-registry). You may want to ask your source whether there is a real difference between Gun and Fon, because apparently Gun is one of the several dialects of Fon. (No, I have no real idea, but this is my impression from Internet sources.)